# Excel-Dna: Co-existence of ExcelCommand and ExcelDNA.Registration Package

Tags: c#, dll, excel-dna

I would like to write the ExcelCommand UDF in the C# program that uses the ExcelDNA Registration package.

However, in order to use the Registration package, if I set explicitRegistraiton="true" in the dna file, the following simple Excel command cannot be loaded. In fact, it is possible to compile, but the UDF command doesn't appear in the Excel add-in tab.

How can I use excel command in a program that uses ExcelDna registration?

```
// C# program
    [ExcelCommand(MenuName ="Test", MenuText ="Test")]
    public static void SayHelloCommand()
    {   
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    }

// .dna file
    <DnaLibrary Name="Registration.Sample Add-In" RuntimeVersion="v4.0" >
      <ExternalLibrary Path="Registration.Sample.dll" ExplicitRegistration="true" LoadFromBytes="true" Pack="true" />
      <Reference Path="ExcelDna.Registration.dll" Pack="true" />
    </DnaLibrary>
```

Comment: You can edit your message to fix the `ExplicitRegistration="true"`

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to fix the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you set `ExplicitRegistration` to `true`, Excel-DNA expects you to register functions and commands yourself.

The same way that you call `ExcelRegistration.GetExcelFunctions().RegisterFunctions()` to register functions, you can also call `ExcelRegistration.GetExcelCommands().RegisterCommands()` to register commands.

e.g.

```
public class AddIn : IExcelAddIn
{
    public void AutoOpen()
    {
        ExcelRegistration
            .GetExcelCommands()
            .RegisterCommands();

        // ...
    }

    public void AutoClose()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. I was able to load the command UDF successfully by adding the code above.